# Start external executable from Java code with streams redirection

Tags: java, stream, outputstream

I need to start external executable in such way that user can interact with program that was just started.

For example in OpenSuse Linux there is a package manager - Zypper. You can start zypper in command mode and give commands like install, update, remove, etc. to it.

I would like to run it from Java code in a way user could interact with it: input commands and see output and errors of the program he started.

Here is a Java code I tried to use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process proc = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("zypper shell");

    InputStream stderr = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;
    char ch;

    while ( (ch = (char)br.read()) != -1)
        System.out.print(ch);

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
}
```

But unfortunately I can only see it's output:

```
zypper>
```

but no matter what I write, my input doesn't affect program that was started.
How can I do what want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get an output stream in order to write to the process:

```
OutputStream out = proc.getOuptutStream();
```

This output stream is piped into the standard input stream of the process, so you can just write to it (perhaps you want to wrap it in a `PrintWriter` first) and the data will be sent to the process' stdin.

Note that it might also be convenient to get the error stream (`proc.getErrorStream`) in order to read any error output that the process writes to its stderr.

API reference:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the converting inside the while condition fails in your example, this seems to work better (I don't run Suse so I haven't tried with Zypper):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    //Process proc = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("zypper shell");
    Process proc = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -t localhost");

    InputStream stderr = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    int i;
    while ( (i = br.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.print((char) i);
    }

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrapped Google Closure Compiler into a .jar-file which is extracted and used in a Process. This compiler only talks via System.in/out/err. There's a big "gotcha" in connecting pipes together, which is just briefly mentioned in the Process javadoc.

> "...failure to promptly write the
>   input stream or read the output stream
>   of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even
>   deadlock."

On Mac OS X the buffer is 16k, and if you don't read it promptly as suggested, the process deadlocks. My only solution to this problem ATM, is a rather nasty busy wait.

https://github.com/algesten/googccwrap/blob/master/src/main/java/googccwrap/GoogleClosureCompilerWrapper.java